# Embed association into ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

In a Rails (5.2) app I have two models: `Project` and `Task`. A project has many tasks but, for auditing reasons, instead of setting up a canonical association with a model in between to keep track of the associations, I store the associated tasks directly inside the project using PostgreSQL array.

The tables look like

```
#Projects 
|id|name|task_ids|
------------------- 
|1| p1  |[1,2]   |
|2| p2  |[1,3]   |


#Tasks 
|id|name|
--------- 
|1| t1  |
|2| t2  |
|3| t3  |
```

I have currently simulated an ActiveRecord association implementing the method below

```
#/models/project.rb
...
def tasks
 Task.find(task_ids)
ene
```

Is there a way to set a real `has_many` association in my `Project` model?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend trying to force this to work with a `has_many` (I'm pretty sure it isn't even possible with ActiveRecord). Why not use a [scope](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) or the `tasks` method as you already implemented?

Comment: I need to get projects with their tasks and I'd like in a single sql query.

Comment: Why not use nosql database? That supports embedding records into one another.

Comment: You mean like a join? `Project.joins("INNER JOIN tasks ON tasks.id IN (1,2)")`

Comment: @vich yes like that but how to refer to `task_ids` for each record? I mean `(1,2)` in your sample must be dynamic according to each project.